# Address of overloaded private member function

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, private-members

I need to call private methods of instance of some classes,
I used a small code snippet for that, it works fine if members aren't   overloaded, otherwise it fails, what is the solution and how to provide addresses of overloaded member functions?

templates.h

```
template <class ClassT>
struct AddressHolder
{
     static typename ClassT::PtrPrivateMemFnT address;
};

// init static member
template <class ClassT>
typename ClassT::PtrPrivateMemFnT AddressHolder<ClassT>::address = 0;

template <class ClassT, typename ClassT::PtrPrivateMemFnT x>
struct GetAddress
{
     GetAddress() { AddressHolder<ClassT>::address = x; }
     static GetAddress instance;
};
template <class ClassT, typename ClassT::PtrPrivateMemFnT x>
GetAddress<ClassT,x> GetAddress<ClassT,x>::instance;
```

main.cpp

```
#include "templates.h"

class HidenGems {
    void privateMethod() {std::cout << "hey1\n";}
    void privateMethod2(int) {std::cout << "hey2\n";}
    void privateMethod2(int,int) {std::cout << "hey2\n";}
};


struct PrivateMethod_TypeHolder {
    typedef void(HidenGems::*PtrPrivateMemFnT)();
};
struct PrivateMethod2_TypeHolder {
    typedef void(HidenGems::*PtrPrivateMemFnT)(int);
};
struct PrivateMethod2_int_int_TypeHolder {
    typedef void(HidenGems::*PtrPrivateMemFnT)(int,int);
};

template struct GetAddress<PrivateMethod_TypeHolder, &HidenGems::privateMethod>;
template class GetAddress<PrivateMethod2_TypeHolder, &HidenGems::privateMethod2>;
template class GetAddress<PrivateMethod2_int_int_TypeHolder, &HidenGems::privateMethod2>;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    HidenGems hg;
    (hg.*AddressHolder<PrivateMethod_TypeHolder>::address)();
    (hg.*AddressHolder<PrivateMethod2_TypeHolder>::address)(100);
    (hg.*AddressHolder<PrivateMethod2_int_int_TypeHolder>::address)(100,100);
    return a.exec();
}
```

I got compile message:

```
/Users/mac/dummy/main.cpp:29: error: 'privateMethod2' is a private member of 'HidenGems'
template class GetAddress<PrivateMethod2_TypeHolder, &HidenGems::privateMethod2>;

/Users/mac/dummy/main.cpp:30: error: 'privateMethod2' is a private member of 'HidenGems'
template class GetAddress<PrivateMethod2_int_int_TypeHolder, &HidenGems::privateMethod2>;
```

Comment: Your error is not caused by fact that methods are overloaded. It occurs because they are not accessible. If you want to use `private` methods like this then you should either make them `public` (which seems to be most suitable in this case), or add everything using them as `friends` of `HidenGems `.

Comment: Interestingly enough, both GCC and Visual Studio will compile it, Clang does not: https://godbolt.org/g/C1UqSa

Comment: @VTT that is why I wrote the templates stuff to be able to access private methods, my intention is be able to call private methods of 3rd party libs

Comment: But you should not do this. These methods are delcared `private` (mostly) for a reason.

Comment: @Jodocus thanks for info, how to fix it for Clang?

Comment: @spin_eight In the general sense, 'compiles' is (roughly) analogous to 'is grammatically/syntactically correct' - there's no guarantee that your sentence makes sense in any/all contexts. I'm inclined to believe Clang is 'in the right', but either way, I wouldn't recommend moving on to Clang without a few sanity tests. As far as I understand, visibility is more than an artificial lock - it's an offset into memory that is also externally inaccessible. ((Phrasing check?)) Best case scenario, you have an address you can't visit. Right?

Comment: Comparatively speaking, it sounds like it would be more reasonable to extend the third-party library/libraries to your liking, either from the source or 'surgically' replacing symbols from the binaries. (I'm not sure about the feasibility/difficulty of the latter, but I imagine exposing members would have far less impact than hiding them. (Heh.))